# How can I query/interrogate a USB device which is not listed in vfs /sys/class/hwmon*?

Tags: c, linux, hid, sysfs

I have a *Corsair HX1000i* PSU, but looks like I can't quite get information for it in the *vfs* `/sys/class/hwmon*`; this is my output:

```
ema@scv:~$ ls -la /sys/class/hwmon/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Jan 21 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 85 root root 0 Jan 21 20:22 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jan 21 20:22 hwmon0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:03:00.0/nvme/nvme0/hwmon0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jan 21 20:22 hwmon1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:0d:00.0/nvme/nvme1/hwmon1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jan 21 20:22 hwmon2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.3/hwmon/hwmon2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jan 21 20:22 hwmon3 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/hwmon3
```

My device is revision 2, id: *1b1c:1c1e* (I can see it in lsusb):

```
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1c1e Corsair HX1000i Power Supply
...
```

And I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 - which is using kernel 5.15.0.
Looking at the [kernel sources](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/drivers/hwmon/corsair-psu.c) seems like rev 2 of my PSU is only supported from kernel [6.1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/drivers/hwmon/corsair-psu.c) forward in terms of appearing in *hwmon** vfs.

Am I correct in expecting this adaptor to appear in this vfs once my kernel gets updated to 6.1+?

What shall I do if I want to query this device myself now? Shall I just use the *hid* part of the driver to communicate with the low level USB interface?
Is there any library to facilitate USB I/O on Linux (happy to write - or borrow - c code)?

I guess [libusb](https://libusb.info/) should do whilst I wait Ubuntu to update the kernel?

Thanks!